# What is the cheapest food safe metal tube I can use for a counter pressure bottle filler?

Tags: bottling

I’ve all the parts to make counter pressure bottle filler (CPBF) except a 8mm outside diameter tube which will be in contact with the beer.

I do have dip tubes in my Cornelius kegs, but before cutting one of those to size (and ordering a replacement for £10) is there a cheaper food safe alternative?

I suspect the lip on the dip tube makes it more expensive than it needs to be for my purpose, it’s not necessary for the CPBF and it’s too long.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Found at Wal-Mart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many counter pressure fillers don't have dip tubes that fill from the bottom of the bottle.

Because the counter pressure system the bottle only has slightly less pressure so there is very little foaming from splashing.

Comment: Thanks, good point regarding reduced foam when under pressure. AlthoUgh the design of the CPBF is such that I need an 8mm tube of some, albeit shorter, length than a dip tube. If seeing the design would help I could add it, but I think it’s pretty much the same as other DIY efforts out there.